# What is best way to convert csv into string?

Tags: php, string, csv

What is best way to convert csv into string ?

There is csv file.txt which is read into variable with file_get_contents() like 1,2,3,4,5 and must be turned into 12345.I could explode it into array and then combine it but maybe there is more efficent way to do it ?

Comment: why? if you just want 12345 there are a many other ways to produce a sequence of numbers.

Comment: I use 1,2,3,4 to generate counter which uses img on one page and on other page I just want string output from  csv as file counterthere is not image based , just simple text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need just 12345 from 1,2,3,4,5 do this:

```
$string = str_replace(",","", file_get_contents("file.txt"));
```